# In `document.getElementById('id')[0]` - what does the [0] means?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about this code snippet:

`var a = document.getElementById("id")[0];`
What does the [0] mean in the object?

Comment: In a selection array with document.querySelector, the [0] selects the first index, but here in your example it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If this is from a very old code, object properties were accessible via index (somewhat 20 years ago). Nowadays, very few elements are implementig indices, `select` is one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` in html always need to be unique & `document.getElementById` returns the element which is represented by this `id`. `document.getElementById` does not return a `NodeList`. A NodeList is array like structure which element can be accessed by the index like `[0]` .

Since `document.getElementById("id")` never returns a `NodeList` so `document.getElementById("id")[0]` is wrong code

Comment: The code is wrong or it is not, depends on the element `gEBI` returns, works fine with `select`.

Answer (score 0):

[0] means first element of array. Or first char for string. Or `0` property of Object.

```js
const obj = {0: 'prop'}
const string = 'String';
const array = [1,2,3];
console.log(
  obj[0],
  string[0],
  array[0]
)
```

document.getElementById("id") returns HTMLElement, not array.

I think this code was dummy copypasted, cause all other `getElementsBy..` funstions returns HTMLCollection (not array, but iterable Object).

Or (may be) somebody set `0` property with htmlelement like this:

```js
id[0] = 'some value';

console.log(
document.getElementById("id")[0]
)
```

```html
<div id='id'></div>
```

Its crazy, but works..